# How to support multiple websites on one domain with different paths as roots in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to create an ASP.NET Core MVC app to support multiple sites on one domain with different paths as roots, please refer to the following example.

- [www.domain.com/site1](http://www.domain.com/site1)
- [www.domain.com/site2](http://www.domain.com/site2)
- [www.domain.com/site3](http://www.domain.com/site3)

etc.

Basically the websites will share the same design, same code base, however, the content, images and the website language might be specific for each website, the content is domain dependent.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: same web app behind all paths? that is what you want? not different web apps, either way IIS supports multiple applications aliases under a website.

Comment: @SilentTremor Each website should have it's own content, images, language, however, they will point to the same code base(same ASP mvc core app), the base functionality should be the same.

Comment: If that's the case, I hate to tell you that the different website is the same website (same ASP mvc core app), and yes you can do that. But no one does it that way, is like having 5 doors to the bathroom.

Comment: @SilentTremor yeah, from the user point of view, there will be different websites, but as you mentioned, there is only one asp mvc core app.
Do you have any suggestions/ideas how to solve it?

Comment: it can be done from web server (IIS) locally or on widows server or from DNS of your cloud platform (Route 53 vs Azure DNS), it can be done from code with routing inside ASP.NET

Comment: It can be the same site. You could have 3 resource folders where you keep your site specific images, content, etc.,  read the siteName from the `Request.Url` and use the resources under the folder with that name.

Comment: @CristianRusanu Thanks for your reply. Sounds a good option. 
What do you suggest for setting up the language that should be used for a specific website?
Previously, we had an MVC application .Net Framework 4 and have used different resource folder for each website, as you mentioned already and also a domain configuration where the domain region, language were defined.
How should we proceed with .NET Core MVC for this particular scenario?
Many thanks

Comment: You could use resource files (`.resx`). It's a default mechanism for dealing with localization in ASP.NET. You will have multiple .resx files for all suported lnaguages. You can set the culture in `Global.asax`   in `Application_AquireRequestState`  using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture)`. Look into the Microsoft documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement，I think you may try add `app.UsePathBase()`; in your startup

I tried and the Result：

[image]